# How to get average polygon?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, polygon, union

Is there a way to get an average polygon of unioned stack of polygons in ArcGIS 10.0?
I would like to get an average polygon that would be centroid (but polygon) of whole stack of polygons.

Comment: what average? The area size? You have to precise your question a little bit. Maybe add additional description or a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a tool in the Geoprocessing Gallery called **[Spatial Average Polygons](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9a30cc1e1ef3486b89629e8f4e3f39fb)** that may do what you are after - at least for a pair of polygons at a time.

Comment: tnx This is one solution if there is no tool for do the same thing with much more polygons at once.